# has anyone translated dietary restrictions in writing from english to korean?

Tags: south-korea, dietary-restrictions

https://justhungry.com/japan-dining-out-cards has printable cards for communicating dietary restrictions in Japan. they translated english to japanese. are there any similar cards or website for korean? i can't speak any korean. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy some on https://allergytranslation.com/cards/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201014062715/https://allergytranslation.com/cards/)), they support 50 languages including Korean.

[image]